# Create a new web application (Access Denied for path 80)

Tags: web-application, 2016

I got the following error while creating a new SharePoint web application on port 80:

> Sorry, something went wrong
>   Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80' is denied.

creating a new SharePoint web application on others ports is working fine.

I am using farm account in SharePoint 2016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new Web Application you have to add host header name to your webapp. This means that your Web App with the host header name "portal" will have the path `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\portal80`, and another web app with host header name "test" will have the path `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\test80`. That way you can use more than one web app running on port 80 since they have different folders in IIS.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply , i created a new one before with the same user without host header on port 80 that worked , but i delete it from CA , come back to create a new one again and got this error , the web application created  but not browsed !! please help ,

Comment: @Aashirya Both Web Apps need to have host headers. Delete and redo again, and it'll solve the problem.

Comment: the same concept is needed for 2013 or it's only for 2016?

Comment: @Aashirya It works the same way for 2013 as 2016!

Comment: additional question please , what about the  web applications with other ports that worked without host header !

Comment: thank you  , it's created with host header because it create a new directory but i can't browse the site : the page can't be displayed  !!!!

Comment: @Aashirya Well. Either you keep that web app and create the second web app on a new port. Or you delete the web app and it's IIS website, but not the database - and recreate them with host header on port 80. When the web app is running, add a site collection which will remove your error of page can't be displayed. Good Luck!

Comment: i created a site collection with the same error !!

Answer (score 2):

Access denied means that their already web application created on that port. So you can't have two web application on single port without hostheaders.

- delete the old web app created on port 80 and make sure no virtual directory exist after deleting on that path.now create new web app.
- use the host headers( either FQDN or using host file entries) to create multiple web applications on port 80
- or you can create web applications on different ports without host headers.

Comment: how to ensure " no virtual directory exist after deleting on that path" I select remove iis and content database !!

Comment: Go to that path and make it does not exist after deleting from central admin. What name for web application you are using?

Comment: the name of web application is the server name , the path 80 exist after delete , please help

Comment: Can you delete that 80 folder? Backup the folder and paste it some other location then delete it on the path